# Check for an array's key existing as a another arrays value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

I have a array called `$menu_array`; and currently looks like this

```
   [0] => Array
    (
        [id_parent_menu] => 4
        [parent_info] => test
        [children_menu] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id_child_menu] => 21
                        [children_info] => test
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id_child_menu] => 22
                        [children_info] => test2.
                    )

            )

    )
```

and so on.

I also have another array `$access` that looks like this:

```
     array(
          [4]='true'
          [22]='true'
     )
```

What I'm trying to do is check to see if the key for the `$access` array exists as a `id_parent_menu`, and then put a key and value of

```
$menu_array[can_view]='true';
```

Then, also check if inside the `$children_menu` array inside of the `$menu_array` if the a `$access` key exists as a `id_child_menu` and set a value of `can_view = true` in there too.

```
$menu_array['children_menu'][1]['can_view']='true';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($menu_array as $key => $value){
  if(isset($access[$value['id_parent_menu']]) && $access[$value['id_parent_menu']])
  {
    $menu_array[$key]['can_view']=true;

    foreach($value['children_menu']  as $key2 => $value2)
      if(isset($access[$value2['id_child_menu']]) && $access[$value2['id_child_menu']])
         $menu_array[$key]['children_menu'][$key2]['can_view']=true;
  }

}
```

(A child item can be visible only if the parent item is visible.)